# how to dual boot ubuntu on a pendrive[USB stick ]?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb

So I have a pendrive with kali linux already installed on it. I want to make it such that i can dual boot kali and ubuntu on the pen drive. Is there any software that I can use?.

I know about xboot, but that only works on windows, and wine emulator can't seem to run it.

I can format and burn the iso through disk image mounter in kali (similar to how it works in ubuntu), by partitioning my pen drive and then burning the iso. Would the bootloader (I'm not sure, but I guess ubuntu default is Syslinux ) recognize it as a dual boot medium ?

Answer (score -1):

As I know, nowdays Ubuntu default bootloader in `GRUB2`, not `syslinux`. So, you should:

1. Split your pendrive into two (or more) partitions.
2. Install Ubuntu on the empty partition - it should recognize Kali.

To be sure not to ruin your pendrive, ypu can try all manipulations into a virtual machine, for example, VirtualBox.

Comment: "nowdays Ubuntu default bootloader in GRUB2, not syslinux" What do you mean? When did Ubuntu used syslinux as the bootloader?

Comment: @Anwar,  @user235315  have guessed that Ubuntu's bootloader is `syslinux` and I claimed that nowdays (to be more `precise`, I'm sure in 12.04 and newer) it is `GRUB2`. I don't know about earlier versions and I suppose that is useless.